# How to solve inequality with unknown degree

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

My inequality looks like this

$$(2^x-1){\sqrt {x^2-x-2}}\ge0$$

I don't know how to deal with $2^x$
Please help me to understand how to solve this kind of equality/inequalities

Answer (score 1):

The domain gives $x\geq2$ or $x\leq-1$.

For $x\leq-1$ we see that $2^x-1<0$, which gives $x=-1$ only.

For all $x\geq2$ our inequality is true and we get the answer:
$$[2,+\infty)\cup\{-1\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^x$ is an exponential function which means it is strictly increasing. Since $2^0=1$, you know that $2^x<1$ for $x < 0$ and $2^x>1$ for $x>0$. That's all you need to know about that function.

Then you just use the fact that $f(x)\cdot g(x) \geq 0$ if either $f(x)\geq0, g(x)\geq0$ or $f(x)\leq 0, g(x)\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2^x-1){\sqrt {x^2-x-2}}\ge0$$

$2^x-1\ge0 $   $\&$  ${\sqrt {x^2-x-2}}\ge0$ since${\sqrt {x^2-x-2}}\ge0 $ for all $x$

Now we have to solve $2^x-1\ge0$

$$2^x\ge1$$

$$x\ge 0$$

But note that ${\sqrt {x^2-x-2}}={\sqrt {(x-2)(x+1)}}$ has a domain $x\ge2$

So the final solution is $x \ge2$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it must be $$2^x\geq1$$ and $$(x+1)(x-2)\geq 0$$
the first inequality gives us $$x\geq 0$$ the second one $$x\geq 2$$ or $$x\le -1$$ thus we get as the solution set $$x\geq 2$$
note the for $x=-1$ we get $$(-\frac{1}{2})\cdot 0=0$$ our inequality is fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

$${ \left( 2^{ x }-1 \right) \sqrt { x^{ 2 }-x-2 }  }\ge 0\\ \left( 2^{ x }-1 \right) { \sqrt { \left( x+1 \right) \left( x-2 \right)  }  }\ge 0\\ \quad \quad \quad \left( x+1 \right) \left( x-2 \right) \ge 0\quad \Rightarrow x\in (-\infty ,-1]\cup [2;+)\\ \\ { 2 }^{ x }\ge 1\quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad { 2 }^{ x }\ge { 2 }^{ 0 }\quad \Rightarrow \quad x\in [0,+\infty )\\ (-\infty ,-1]\cup [2;+)\cap [0,+\infty )=[2;+\infty )$$
and considering the $x=-1$ is also solution 
so final the answer is $[2;+\infty )\cup \{ -1\} \quad \\ $

Comment: I think your solution is wrong.

Comment: which part exactly?

Comment: $-1$ is also solution.

Comment: Oh,my stupidy,thank you

Comment: Now it's all right.+1